# Why is my code throwing an out of index error

Tags: python

I'm making a thing that will check through a series of arrays (effectively a matrix) with letters in them and check if that letter is within another smaller array to make a mega wordsearch sort of thing

**My code**

```
import Board

i = 0
while i < 10:
    print("whats the " + str(i + 1) + " rd ten letter line you want in the board")
    temp_line = input().split()
    print(temp_line)
    j = 1
    while j <= len(temp_line):
        Board.Board[i + 1][j] = temp_line[j - 1]
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

**The board that will be cleaned up, has a hash border for border checking**

```
Board = ["#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"],
["#", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "#"],
["#", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "#"],
["#", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "#"],
["#", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "#"],
["#", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "#"],
["#", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "#"],
["#", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "#"],
["#", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "#"],
["#", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "#"],
["#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"]
```

And then it throws this error out

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    Board.Board[i + 1][j] = temp_line[j - 1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Despite the ugly board I've looked manually step by step through the code and of course do not see where anything could possibly be out of range.

What is it?

Comment: I suggest naming your file board lowercase b.

Comment: If you can’t figure it out, put a `print` on the line right before the one that raises the error and output all relevant variables to see what their values are.

Answer (score 0):

`Board.Board[i + 1][j]` returns an `IndexError: tuple index out of range` error because the length of your board is 1.

Running: `len(Board.Board) //returns 1`

Add an `opening and closing bracket` to your Board tuple and `len(Board.Board)` should now return 11 and the code will run.